# Sending request to website using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http

i am trying to send an HTTP request to specific website and i am facing error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.google.com/. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

say for instance that i want to send request to Google.com and receive the HTML response.
my code was written using JQUERY AJAX:

```
function sendRequest(URL) {
          $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:URL,
            success:function(result){console.log(result);}
          });
        }
```

Comment: Short answer is you cannot unless the target site has explicitly allowed it via CORS or some other explicit method of allowing it. This is a foundational security measure and cannot be bypassed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959912/ajax-cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows-reading-the)

Comment: Think the message says it all "disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.google.com/. (Reason: **CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing**)."

Comment: do you need a response? if not, use a form, img, or beacon.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can help you : https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#Troubleshooting%20CORS-Related-Problems

Look this one also : [Access-Control-Allow-Origin error sending a jQuery Post to Google API's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114436/access-control-allow-origin-error-sending-a-jquery-post-to-google-apis)