# Cross-Origin Request Blocked Wordpress and Codeigniter

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

I am facing the strange problem on the wordpress website . What is really happening that i have a form in the wordpress website main page and the form submit the data in the Codeigniter Controller function .

Whenever i submit the form i got this message

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://xxx/ci/user/signup/. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Where as if i putt the same code in the php file at this path

http://xxx/ci/signup.php

It submit the data sucessfully and everything goes well . But whenever i try to submit data from the wordpress site it gives me that error . I also check the htaccess file and limit it worpdress only commands .

I am not getting why i am getting this issue when i am using it on same domain and both time i use http to access the url .

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/22392080/4684564

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add these header in the server side script.i.e in codeigniter page header

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

Answer (score 0):

**modify config/config.php file like below :**

$config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");

$config['base_url'] .= "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$config['base_url'] .=str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

(replace baseurl method with top code)