# Why does my POST request in Postman work fine but when not on the client side (browser)?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

I have a Laravel and React.js project that of which are separate code bases. When I login in Postman with login endpoint followed by uploading name of the file with another endpoint (both of them POST requests), the `filePath`, `email` and `user_id` are stored successfully in the db.

However, when I do try this on the browser - I get a `200` but oddly enough, nothing's stored in the db.

In Postman, it somehow detects what user's logged in which allows me to store the aforementioned information into the DB without problems.

What am I doing wrong here in my frontend and backend code that's not allowing me to do this on the browser?  I've hit a wall with this one and not sure where to from here.

FYI:  The `dd($user);` returns the correct information.

Please let me know if you need more information :)

Here's my `Upload.js` file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Upload extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedFile: null,
            id: null,
            email: ''
        };
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Inside componentDidMount()");
        let id = localStorage.getItem("id");
        let email = localStorage.getItem("email");
        this.setState({
            id: id,
            email: email
        })
        console.log(id);
        console.log(email);
    }

    onFormSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.fileUpload(this.state.selectedFile);
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({ selectedFile: e.target.files[0] }, () => this.state.selectedFile);
    }

    fileUpload(file) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("access_token").slice(13,-8);

        console.log(accessToken);
        console.log(this.state.id);
        console.log(this.state.email);
        console.log(file.name);
        formData.append('file',file);

        const headers = {
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }

        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/wall-of-fame', formData, {headers})
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form encType='multipart/form-data' id="login-form" className="form" >
                <input type="file" name="file" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                <button type="submit" onClick={this.onFormSubmit}>Upload</button>
            </form>
        );
    }

}

export default Upload;
```

Here's my `FileUploadController.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class FileUploadController extends Controller {

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $user = Auth::user();

//        dd($user);
        if($user) {
            $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $email = Auth::user()->email;
            $filePath = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
            $data = [
                'file_path' => $filePath,
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'email' => $email
            ];
            DB::table('mydb.photos')->insert($data);
        }

        return response()->json($user);
    }
}
```

Here's my `api.php` file:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });
});

Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('signup', 'AuthController@signup');
    Route::post('wall-of-fame', 'FileUploadController@store');

    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'auth:api'
    ], function() {
        Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
        Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
        Route::get('wall-of-fame', 'FileUploadController@fileUpload');
    });
});
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to set the header of the response with `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"`

You can read this link to get more information [Cross-Origin Request Blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363268/cross-origin-request-blocked)

Comment: Can you capture the header response at Postman and the browser then show here

Comment: I've just posted the header response from Postman and browser on my original post

Comment: Yup, but you have taken the wrong picture with the postman
This is I mean
https://ibb.co/HFjg7jH

Comment: Ok, I've updated my original post.  The funny part's that if I remove `Content-Type` and `Authorization`, the POST request goes through successfully!

Comment: That really funny! :v :v